# Ruby if shorthand + map shorthand

Tags: ruby, dictionary

How do I use a map(&:name) shorthand inside a

`condition ? map(&:name) : name`

if shorthand?

I got a syntax error, ruby is trying to evaluate the first colon.

Comment: Can you add a complete, working code snippet which demonstrates your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what your problem is but here is a way to use "`map(&:name)`" inside a conditional:

```
require 'ostruct' # For demonstration using OpenStruct.
arr = [OpenStruct.new(:name => 'Foo'),
       OpenStruct.new(:name => 'Bar'),
       OpenStruct.new(:name => 'Gah')]
name = 'Testing'
(true  ? arr.map(&:name) : name) # => ["Foo", "Bar", "Gah"]
(false ? arr.map(&:name) : name) # => "Testing"
```